# How to decide whether a logical formula is satisfiable

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, satisfiability

I'm trying to solve one logical problem. I have Language `L={P}` with equality (there can be '='). And we have 4 formulas an theories of this language.

We have to decide, for each formula, whether it is satisfiable.

These are formulas:
$$
A: \exists{x,y,z}; \hspace{1cm} (x \ne y) \land(x \ne z) \land (y \ne z)\\
B: \forall{x,y}; \hspace{1cm} P(x,y)\\
C: \forall{x},\exists{y}; \hspace{1cm} P(x,y)\\
D: \exists{y},\forall{x}; \hspace{1cm} P(x,y)
$$

and theories:

$$
T_1: \{A,B\}\\
T_2: \{A,C,\neg{D}\}\\
T_3: \{A,\neg{C},D\}\\
$$

I've probably solved **T1** and **T2** but I can't solve **T3**.

So:

**T1:** The formula A forces that there must be at least 3 atoms in universum. So I've chosen this universum: $\{1,2,3\}$ and the Predicate $P(x,y): (x=y) \lor (x \ne y)$

**T2:** The same thing: universum: $\{1,2,3\}$ and the $P(x,y): x \equiv 0 \hspace{2mm}(\bmod y)$

**T3:** $\neg{C}: \nexists{x},\exists{y}; P(x,y): \exists{x},\forall{y}; \neg P(x,y)$

Now I'm lost. I can't find any model but I can't decide and prove that this Theory is not satisfiable.

Could you help me?

Comment: An aside on notation/terminology: "universum"?? maybe, if we're studying medieval logic, but we aren't. "universe" will do just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose both $\neg C$ and $D$, where:
$$\begin{align}
\neg C &\iff \exists x\, \forall y \,\neg P(x,y) \\
D &\iff \exists y\, \forall x\, P(x,y).
\end{align}$$
By $\neg C$, there's some $x_0$ such that 
$$\forall y \,\neg P(x_0,y).\tag{1}
$$ 
By $D$, there's some $y_0$ such that 
$$\forall x\, P(x,y_0).\tag{2}
$$
Instantiating (1), we have $\neg P(x_0, y_0)$; instantiating (2), $P(x_0, y_0)$: contradiction.

So **T3** is inconsistent.